# Type has no member subscript, in SwiftUI with CoreData

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui

I tried looking for an answer to this question, but none of the past-answers relate to core data specifically.

I am trying to create a function that removes my data from a scrollview, from CoreData, onDelete. It's throwing me the following error next to **let delete = SavedPoem[index]":   Type "SavedPoem" has no member "subscript"**.

"SavedPoem" is an entity stored in CoreData, thus I am unsure how to perform any of the suggested recommendations in past questions.

Code here:

```
import SwiftUI

struct SavedPoemList: View {
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    @FetchRequest(entity: SavedPoem.entity(), sortDescriptors: []) var savedpoems : FetchedResults<SavedPoem>
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack (alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
            
            HStack{
                Text("Your Saved Poems")
                    .font(.title)
                    .fontWeight(.black)
                    .foregroundColor(.black)

                    
                Spacer()
                    
                    
            }.padding(.bottom)
            .padding(.trailing)
            .padding(.leading)
               
            ScrollView {
                    
                ForEach(savedpoems, id:\.title) {SavedPoem in
                   
                    NavigationLink (destination: DetailViewSaved()){
                      
                        ZStack {
                            
                            Rectangle()
                                .fill(Color.white)
                                .frame(width: UIScreen.screenWidth - 40, height: 70)
                                .cornerRadius(5)
                                .padding([.horizontal], 20)
//                                .shadow(color: .gray, radius: 10)
                                                        
                            HStack {
                                VStack (alignment: .leading){
                                    Text("\(SavedPoem.title ?? "")")
                                        .font(.headline)
                                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                                        .lineLimit(1)
                                        
                                    
                                    Text("\(SavedPoem.author ?? "")")
                                        .font(.subheadline)
                                        .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                                }
                                .padding(.horizontal)
                                Spacer()
                                
                            }
                            .padding()
                        }.padding(.bottom,10)
                        
                    }
                }.onDelete(perform: remove)
                
            }
            .navigationTitle("My Saved Poems")
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
            .padding(.bottom, 30)
                    

            }
        .padding(.horizontal)
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
        
    }
        func remove(at offsets : IndexSet) {
            for index in offsets {
                let delete = SavedPoem[index]
                self.moc.delete(delete)
            }
            try? self.moc.save()
        }
}

struct SavedPoemList_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SavedPoemList()
    }
}
```

CoreData SavedPoem Structure:
[image: coredata]

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you meant to use `savedpoems` instead of `SavedPoem`

```
for index in offsets {
    let delete = savedpoems[index]
    self.moc.delete(delete)
}
```

Comment: That's correct, thanks! It builds, but the .onDelete doesn't seem to do anything. Do you know if it just doesn't work on the simulator? Does .onDelete work with ScrollViews? Or am I missing something maybe?

Comment: This is out of topic, but yes ScrollView does not handle onDelete like List, if you that expected. Next might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/63833510/12299030 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/63364795/12299030.